# ASP.NET MVC Encoding Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app is passing a name to/from the database. I've recently discovered a bug associated with ampersands (&).

In my database, I see the name "A & W".

I am displaying this value in my UI using the following:

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" value="@Html.Raw(Model.Name)" />
```

When I view the source, I can see that the following HTML gets rendered in the browser.

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" value="A & W" />
```

So far, so good. However, when I click save, and I set a breakpoint in my controller action, I can see the `Name` property on my Model is now "A & W". What's worse is, everytime I save it, additional amp values get added.

How do I remedy this?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you think the `Name` property should be if that's the actual value of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, so I used the [AllowHtml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute on my property in my model.

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

If you aren't using Code First, you can apply this attribute on top of your action also:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowHtml]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Modify(ModelClass model) {}
```